# About find django static image

Tags: django-templates

I used templates forloop print my data like:

```
{% for i in data %}

    {% with '../img/'|add:i.OrgName|add:'.png' as image_static %} 

        <img src="{% static image_static %}">

    {% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

「i.OrgName」 like A0001, A0002, A0003, A0004...etc

Images file Name just like A0001.png, A0002.png, A0003.png and Noimg.png

If I don't have a A0004.png, how can join control in forloop?

Pseudocode maybe like:

```
for i in data:
    if can find i.png:
        <img src="i.png"">
    else:
       <img src="Noimg.png"">
```

Thank you for any help in getting started prior!

Best Regards

Comment: use a custom templatetag

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am stupid.

i forget can used  onerror !!!

for revision code:

```
{% for i in data %}

    {% with '../img/'|add:i.OrgName|add:'.png' as image_static %} 

        <img src="{% static image_static %}" 
          onerror='this.src="{% static '../img/Noimg.png' %}">

    {% endwith %}

{% endfor %}
```

This worked for me, but better way!